# List comprehension function for odd-even numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to print a list containing 2 lists at index 0 and 1. One list contains even numbers and the other one odd numbers.
Also, I want to do it with list comprehension and use only one list variable.

```
even_odd = [[],[]]
even_odd = [even_odd[0].append(a) if a%2 == 0 else even_odd[1].append(a) for a in range(20)]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]]
```

Using list comprehension

Comment: Please try to include a sample input and expected output.

Comment: The example you provided does nothing with anything outside itself, so it just generates a list of 20 strings, alternating between "even" and "odd". What were you hoping to achieve based on the two lists you mentioned?

Comment: @Grismar I think he wants like `Input: range(0, 20)` and `Output: [[0,2,4,...,18], [1, 3, 5, ..., 19]]` which imo impossible

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx Why do you think it's impossible?

Comment: Yes @xxMrPHDxx is right ..

Comment: I wish to obtain the output '[[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]]'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the accepted answer is not actually a solution to the problem posed - it simply provides two expressions for the single expression requested; the real answer is "it can't be done as requested, but the simple alternative isn't that bad".

Comment: @Grismar, xxMrPHDxx provided one answer which was matching my required solution. I don't know why he deleted !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with two `range` by iterating in 2 interval

```
even_odd = [list(range(0, 19, 2)), list(range(1, 20, 2))]
# [[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]]
```

Comment: I don't wish to obtain the answer but more importantly use list comprehension to achieve it. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @AmitPathak This is just a shortened version of `[[i for i in range(0, 19, 2)], [i for i in range(1, 20, 2)]]`.